# git: what commit was I on before I merged?

Tags: git

I just did a fast forward merge with a lot of commits in it, and it broke some functionality.

(how) Can I find out what commit I was on before that merge?

Comment: Try `git-reflog`

Comment: There is probably a silver bullet way of doing this, but if you made the last commit in the branch in question, and you know the date, then it should be pretty easy to find the commit you want just by using `git log`.

Comment: Tim - that is the not the situation I find myself in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted in comments, you can use the command `git reflog` for this. The *reflog* creates all movements of Git branch pointers. This includes actions like:

- Creating new commits in a branch with `git commit` (or other commands that create new commits like `git cherry-pick` or others)
- Resetting the branch pointer to another commit with `git reset`
- Merging another branch both *fast-forward merged* and regular *3-way merges*.

To see how the `master` branch tip changed over time, use the command

```
> git reflog master
```

This will generate a history that looks like the following:

```
e03b939 master@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
fa6a265 master@{1}: commit: Added section on project background
c9957fd master@{2}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'feature/foobar'
9d4e390 master@{3}: pull: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
536c04a master@{4}: commit (merge): Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
d1cf7ad master@{5}: commit: Fix broken formatting
a0cfc5c master@{6}: pull: Fast-forward
c638351 master@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD^
303307e master@{8}: commit: Add awesome feature
...
```

The first line `master@{0}` contains the commit that your `master` branch is currently pointing on. The second line `master@{1}` will show you the commit that your `master` branch pointed to before doing the fast-forward merge.

To reset your master branch to that commit, then simply use `git reset`:

```
> git reset --hard fa6a265
```