# After doing `git pull` in a local repository, is it possible to find out which commit was the last before the git pull?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-checkout

I did a git pull. Then, a fast forward merge happened and multiple objects and commits were added to my local repository.

Some things went wrong and I would like to go back to how the local repository was before pulling new objects from upstream.

Hence, I would like to **checkout the last commit** before pulling. The problem is that I **do not** remember what was the last commit before pulling.

Is there a command to show the last commit before pulling? Maybe another command that shows what as added on the last git pull?

Thanks.

Comment: _"Some things went wrong"_ - what specifically?

Comment: The repository in which git pull happened is used by an application. The application code is not ready for the new changes. This is why I want to get it back to the previous state. Things were working before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: what commit was I on before I merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863843/git-what-commit-was-i-on-before-i-merged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do mean something like?

`git reflog <branch>`

It is explained here: [git: what commit was I on before I merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863843/git-what-commit-was-i-on-before-i-merged)